# HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject returns null but the value is available through Resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, embedded-resource

I'm trying to access values from a resx resource file using **HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject.**

The resource file is in a folder called Resources and has the CustomTool property set to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator as per K. Scott Allen: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx

**The resources are being built and embedded** (I can see then in the assembly via ILSpy) and I can access the values in code using:

```
var b = MyApp.Resources.GlobalStrings.VendorUITitle;
```

But trying to access them via **GetGlobalResourceObject always returns null**

```
var s = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyApp.Resources.GlobalStrings", "VendorUITitle");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by setting the **Custom Tool** of my resource file to be **GlobalResourceProxyGenerator**

And the **Build Action** to **Content** and **Copy to Output Directory** property to **Copy Always**

[image: Resource File Properties]

If I didn't do this then when I published to production calls to **HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject** would always return null.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create resource file under App_GlobalResources
2. Set Build Action to Content
3. Set Copy to Output Directory to Do not copy
4. Ensure you have App_GlobalResources folder in deployed aplication